# Pyspark: TypeError: unionByName() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allowMissingColumns'

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

While using these line of code which is in the documenttion of Pyspark unionByName

```
df =spark.createDataFrame(data,columns)

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 2, 3]], ["col0", "col1", "col2"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([[4, 5, 6]], ["col1", "col2", "col3"])
df1.unionByName(df2, allowMissingColumns=True).show()
```

got this error:

```
    unionByName() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allowMissingColumns'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    TypeError: unionByName() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allowMissingColumns'
```

Is there any other way to do this, in my code

```
   df1: ["col0", "col1", "col2","col3"]
   df2: ["col1", "col2"]
```

I want to union them on `["col1", "col2"]` and expect the `col0` and `col3` to be null after `union`.

Comment: What version are you using? Note that allowMissingColumn is available from version 3.1.0.

Comment: Works well for me, check that you are on the right version

Comment: yeah, I am using version 2.4 How can I achieve same functionality, is there any workaround

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting this error is because you're on a Spark version that does not yet support the `allowMissingColumns` argument to the `unionByName` function.

This feature is available from [this commit](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/8bd3770552), which is available from version 3.1.0.

If you're on an earlier version, you could do the following as a workaround:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df1 = spark.createDataFrame([[1, 2, 3]], ["col0", "col1", "col2"])
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([[4, 5, 6]], ["col1", "col2", "col3"])

not_in_df1 = set(df2.columns) - set(df1.columns)
for col in not_in_df1:
    df1 = df1.withColumn(col, lit(None).cast(StringType()))

not_in_df2 = set(df1.columns) - set(df2.columns)
for col in not_in_df2:
    df2 = df2.withColumn(col, lit(None).cast(StringType()))

df1.unionByName(df2).show()
+----+----+----+----+
|col0|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   3|null|
|null|   4|   5|   6|
+----+----+----+----+
```

So essentially, you're creating the columns needed in each of the dataframes in order to have the same column composition. Also, we're using `lit(None).cast(StringType())` to create literal null columns.

It's a bit of a hack, but does get the job done.